# What is this wire-to-board connector?

Tags: connector, adapter, clamp

For my project I want to use the circuit board of a SRAM Eagle AXS controller.

But I can’t figure out which kind of connectors they used for this. The male connector is 4 mm wide.

Maybe someone has already seen or worked with this kind of PCB connector before?

[image: Connectors]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a "[parallel mate](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=parallel_mate_w2b_conn)" connector (My site). Specifically, it seems to be a [Hirose DF57](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=parallel_mate_w2b_conn&s=DF57).

https://www.hirose.com/en/product/p/CL0666-0112-0-00

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This could be it! Do you maybe happen to know where I can get those as well?

Comment: The link that @Davide Andrea provided lists buying options. In general you can use OctoPart to find component availability.

Comment: " where I can get those as well?" Sorry, no. They seem to be obsolete. I suggest you look into [similar connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=parallel_mate_w2b_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-500-|1.2|2|||). (My site.)